# Change default language in Scilab on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scilab

My OS X installation is not in English.
I suppose for that reason my version of Scilab UI is shown in a mixture of my OS language and English, which is an annoyance. 
Looking in the manual of Scilab reveals there is a command to set the default language, it is called 'setdefaultlanguage', but it comes with the limitation that it only works for Windows platforms.
Is there a Mac user who achived to change the UI language? If so, how did you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Wow there was no easy way to accomplish this.
I had to modify the starting script of the Scilab binary.
I changed the $MORE_OPTS variable to permanently contain the parameter "-l en", which switches the language to English.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to open Scilab with the desired language option, even if this does not change the default language option. For Scilab 6.0.2, you can use the following command:

```
/Applications/scilab-6.0.2.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/scilab -l en_US
```

In this command, "en_US" stands for the english language. You can see this [link](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.2/en_US/setlanguage.html) for other language options.